# Derivation of formula for sum of first $n$ squares in Courant

Tags: summation

In Courant's *Differential and Integral Calculus* (Vol. I), he presents the following derivation of a formula for the sum of the squares of the first $n$ integers:

[Link to Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOAYj.png)

However, when I substitute $v=0,1,2,...n$ and sum all of the resulting equations, I find that

$\displaystyle (1^3+\cdots +(n+1)^3)-(1^3+\cdots +n^3)=3(1^2+\cdots +n^2)+3(1+\cdots +n)+1$

and hence that

$\displaystyle (n+1)^3=3S_2+3S_1+1$

Which does not lead to the correct formula, since the $n$ is missing.

**Question: where does the $n$ on the RHS of Courant's result [i.e. $(n+1)^3=3S_2+3S_1+n+1$] come from?**

Comment: A. Sable, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, could yo please edit your question to show what you are asking, as there does not appear to be a question

Comment: What do you mean 'a part' of them? The three terms are separate as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry read it wrong. Here is an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to sum the $1$ as well. Allow me to show you.
$$(v+1)^3-v^3=3v+3v+1$$
$$\sum_{v=0}^{n} (v+1)^3-v^3 = \sum_{v=0}^{n} 3v^2+3v+1$$
$$(n+1)^3=3\Bigg(\sum_{v=0}^{n}v^2\Bigg) +3\Bigg(\sum_{v=0}^{n}v\Bigg)+ \Bigg(\sum_{v=0}^{n}1\Bigg)$$
And so by substituting $S_1$ and $S_2$, we get
$$(n+1)^3=3S_2+3S_1+n+1$$